# Count string occurrence in a list in cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In python, i have a data frame like this

|  | Fruits |
| --- | --- |
| James | [Apple, Pear, Apple] |
| Peter | [Apple, Pear, Apple] |

I would like to get the count of both apple and pear. Would appreciate any help in this.

|  | Fruits | Apple | Pear |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | [Apple, Pear, Apple] | 2 | 1 |
| Peter | [Apple, Pear, Apple] | 2 | 1 |

I tried using this :

```
d['Apple'] = (d.Fruits == 'Apple').sum() and
d['Apple'] = (d.Fruits.values == 'Apple').sum()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution if performance is important and need count all values:

```
from collections import Counter

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame([Counter(x) for x in df.Fruits.to_numpy()], index=df.index))
print (df)
                     Fruits  Apple  Pear
James  [Apple, Pear, Apple]      2     1
Peter  [Apple, Pear, Apple]      2     1
```

If want test values sepately:

```
df['Apple'] = df.Fruits.apply(lambda x: sum(y == 'Apple' for y in x))
df['Pear'] = df.Fruits.apply(lambda x: sum(y == 'Pear' for y in x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) + [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
res = pd.concat((df, df['Fruits'].apply(pd.Series.value_counts)), 1)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
                     Fruits  Apple  Pear
James  [Apple, Pear, Apple]      2     1
Peter  [Apple, Pear, Apple]      2     1
```

A more general approach is to do:

```
res = pd.concat((df, df['Fruits'].apply(pd.Series.value_counts).fillna(0)), 1)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and `groupby.value_counts` with `unstack`:

```
out = (df.join(df['Fruits'].explode().groupby(level=0).value_counts()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)))
```

---

```
print(out)

                     Fruits  Apple  Pear
James  [Apple, Pear, Apple]      2     1
Peter  [Apple, Pear, Apple]      2     1
```

Answer (score 1):

For any list you can use `Collections.Counter()`
it works with an easy logic such as `Counter(item)`You can loop your entire list and counter your item it will give your output.